# html to pdf from bash with unicode (UTF-8) support

Tags: html, bash, pdf, unicode, utf-8

Is there a good way to convert html to PDF from bash with Unicode (UTF-8) support?
I would expect the same result as if I were to use a PDF printer and print a page from Firefox.

Usage Example:

`curl http://www.wikipedia.org/ | html2pdf_bash_command > /tmp/wikipedia.org.pdf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something with `xfvb` and a browser or use a small qt component `wkhtmltopdf`. Also if you have a full gnome installed on your environment you can use `gnome-web-print`.